# Program keep running after terminating

Tags: java, multithreading

I am writing a code in Java to run a task every 10 sec. However, when I stop the program from netbeans, it's still keep running

```
while(true)

{
....
Thread.sleep(10000);
}
```

Comment: And the question is?!?

Comment: Even after I  go to Run-> Stop Run, and exit the IDE, I can still see the program running, It should stop when I exit the IDE

Comment: Do you catch an InterruptedException?

Comment: kill by using system command like killall -9 java it will kill all java processes

Answer (score 0):

Closing IDE does not mean terminating all your projects.

Answer (score 0):

This means netbeans is closing your main thread and keeping your others running. Try perform a System.exit somewhere in your code and you'll see that it finishes running.